# Google Blogger API - cannot create a post

Tags: asp.net, google-api, blogger

I am using Google Blogger API to create posts programmatically in a blog I created. I am using the code below to try and create a new post but it keeps giving me the error:

```
*Execution of request failed: https://galeajean.blogspot.com/ ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.*
```

the code I am using is:

```
Service service = new Service("blogger", "blogger-example-1");
service.Credentials = new GDataCredentials(actualusername, actualpassword);
GDataGAuthRequestFactory factory = (GDataGAuthRequestFactory)service.RequestFactory;
factory.AccountType = "GOOGLE";
Uri blogPostUri = new Uri("http://galeajean.blogspot.com/");
AtomEntry createdEntry = PostNewEntry(service, blogPostUri);

static AtomEntry PostNewEntry(Service service, Uri blogPostUri)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nPublishing a blog post");
        AtomEntry createdEntry = null;
        if (blogPostUri != null)
        {
            // construct the new entry
            AtomEntry newPost = new AtomEntry();
            newPost.Title.Text = "Marriage!";
            newPost.Content = new AtomContent();
            newPost.Content.Content = "<div xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>" +
                "<p>Mr. Darcy has <em>proposed marriage</em> to me!</p>" +
                "<p>He is the last man on earth I would ever desire to marry.</p>" +
                "<p>Whatever shall I do?</p>" +
                "</div>";
            newPost.Content.Type = "xhtml";
            newPost.Authors.Add(new AtomPerson());
            newPost.Authors[0].Name = "Elizabeth Bennet";
            newPost.Authors[0].Email = "liz@gmail.com";

            createdEntry = service.Insert(blogPostUri, newPost);

        }
        return createdEntry;
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated guys....thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok,i gt the prblm...
problem is in your blog blogPostUri..
this should be.

```
Uri blogPostUri = new Uri("http://www.blogger.com/feeds/" + blogID + "/posts/default");
```

Comment: user2374372...I love you :) tried it and it works perfectly mate thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

remove the line

```
newPost.Content.Type = "xhtml";
```

thn check again...because it may be possible that the content type you posting not meet the stndrds of blogger policies...it may help...